# Sorting strings by characters first

Tags: c++, string, sorting, comparison, stdstring

I am using std::map in C++ and it's sorting keys in alphabetical way, like this:

`AAA, AA0, AA1, AAB, AC1 = AA0->AA1->AAA->AAB->AC1`

But I would like to sort it in a different way:

`AAA, AA0, AA1, AAB, AC1 = AAA->AAB->AA0->AA1->AC1`

How to write a comparing class for std::map, which will solve my problem?
I completely don't know how to do that.
Here's a definition of my comparing class:

```
struct Comp
{
    bool operator()(const std::string& lhs, const std::string& rhs) const
    {
       //dont know what should I write here
    };
};
```

Comment: I think @juanchopanza purposely left that as an exercise for you. :P It's also worth pointing out that if you want to treat strings like this regularly, you might be better off providing a user-defined `char_traits`.

Comment: What do you mean by the second order? Can you describe it by a well formed algorithm?

Comment: Start by formulating your algorithm in plain words, and then translate these words to code. IOW, without a clear definition (not just examples) of what you want to achieve, you can't hope to code anything. With it, it's often pretty straightforward.

Comment: @M.M. : he wants the numeric character to come after the letters when comparing...

Comment: The best way to learn something new is to see some example of this. Maybe could you give me some guidelines? It's kinda too hard for me, I have just started using STL in my code. Please help me :).

Comment: @user2342783 If you knew that both strings were **a single character**, would you be able to write that function?  If you can write that, you're most of the way there.

Comment: @DrewDormann Provided you know that `std::lexicographical_compare` exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, all you really want is for the digits
to sort after the alphabetical characters.  Anytime you can
resume the sorting criteria down to an ordering of the letters,
you can use `std::lexicographical_compare`, passing it
a comparison operator which does what you need on the
characters.

I usually combine this in a single comparision operator:

```
struct Comp
{
    bool isDigit( char lhs ) const
    {
        return ::isdigit( static_cast<unsigned char>( lhs ) );
    }

    bool operator()( char lhs, char rhs ) const
    {
        return isDigit( lhs ) == isDigit( rhs )
            ? lhs < rhs
            : isDigit( rhs );
    }

    bool operator()( std::string const& lhs, std::string const& rhs ) const
    {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(
            lhs.begin(), lhs.end(), rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), *this);
    }
};
```

For more generalized comparisons, you can provide a map of
values to compare, and use it:

```
bool Comp::operator()( char lhs, char rhs ) const
{
    return myMap[ static_cast<unsigned char>( lhs ) ]
        <  myMap[ static_cast<unsigned char>( rhs ) ];
}
```

This will allow any imaginable ordering, as long as the ordering
can be done character by character.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Visual Studio says, that `std::lexicographical_compare( lhs, rhs, *this);` is given too few arguments (expects 4 or 5 arguments).

Comment: @user2342783 Sorry.  Of course, it takes iterators, instead of strings.  I'll fix it.

Comment: Many thanks! I promise, that I will learn how to use it, without other's help :)!